# PostgreSQL master not restarting

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I have 3 node HA setup of PostgreSQL.

1. Primary node (192.168.50.3)
2. Secondary node (192.168.50.4)
3. Secondary node (192.168.50.5)

Both secondary node are pointing to primary and `recovery.conf` looks like below:

```
standby_mode          = 'on'
primary_conninfo      = 'host=192.168.50.3 port=5432 user=<uname> password=<pass_herr> sslmode=require sslcompression=0'
trigger_file = '/tmp/MasterNow'
recovery_target_timeline = 'latest'
```

Now, when i restart the PostgreSQL on primary (50.3), i am getting following `FATAL` in PostgreSQL log.

```
Aug  7 07:58:55 cluster-node1 postgres[1671]: [1-1] 2019-08-07 07:58:55 UTC LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
Aug  7 07:58:55 cluster-node1 postgres[1671]: [2-1] 2019-08-07 07:58:55 UTC LOG:  could not create IPv6 socket for address "::": Address family not supported by protocol
Aug  7 07:58:55 cluster-node1 postgres[1671]: [3-1] 2019-08-07 07:58:55 UTC LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
Aug  7 07:58:55 cluster-node1 postgres[1671]: [4-1] 2019-08-07 07:58:55 UTC LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"
Aug  7 07:58:55 cluster-node1 postgres[1671]: [5-1] 2019-08-07 07:58:55 UTC LOG:  ending log output to stderr
Aug  7 07:58:55 cluster-node1 postgres[1671]: [5-2] 2019-08-07 07:58:55 UTC HINT:  Future log output will go to log destination "syslog".
Aug  7 07:58:55 cluster-node1 postgres[1679]: [6-1] 2019-08-07 07:58:55 UTC LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-08-07 07:58:55 UTC
Aug  7 07:58:55 cluster-node1 postgres[1671]: [6-1] 2019-08-07 07:58:55 UTC LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
Aug  7 08:00:44 cluster-node1 postgres[1671]: [7-1] 2019-08-07 08:00:44 UTC LOG:  received fast shutdown request
Aug  7 08:00:44 cluster-node1 postgres[1671]: [8-1] 2019-08-07 08:00:44 UTC LOG:  aborting any active transactions
Aug  7 08:00:44 cluster-node1 postgres[1671]: [7-1] 2019-08-07 08:00:44 UTC LOG:  received fast shutdown request
Aug  7 08:00:44 cluster-node1 postgres[1671]: [8-1] 2019-08-07 08:00:44 UTC LOG:  aborting any active transactions
Aug  7 08:00:44 cluster-node1 postgres[1712]: [7-1] 2019-08-07 08:00:44 UTC FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
Aug  7 08:00:44 cluster-node1 postgres[1701]: [7-1] 2019-08-07 08:00:44 UTC FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
Aug  7 08:00:44 cluster-node1 postgres[1699]: [7-1] 2019-08-07 08:00:44 UTC FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
Aug  7 08:00:44 cluster-node1 postgres[1697]: [7-1] 2019-08-07 08:00:44 UTC FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
Aug  7 08:00:44 cluster-node1 postgres[1702]: [7-1] 2019-08-07 08:00:44 UTC FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
Aug  7 08:00:44 cluster-node1 postgres[1709]: [7-1] 2019-08-07 08:00:44 UTC FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
Aug  7 08:00:44 cluster-node1 postgres[1700]: [7-1] 2019-08-07 08:00:44 UTC FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
Aug  7 08:00:44 cluster-node1 postgres[1971]: [7-1] 2019-08-07 08:00:44 UTC FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
Aug  7 08:00:44 cluster-node1 postgres[1708]: [7-1] 2019-08-07 08:00:44 UTC FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
Aug  7 08:00:44 cluster-node1 postgres[1671]: [9-1] 2019-08-07 08:00:44 UTC LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 1685) exited with exit code 1
Aug  7 08:00:44 cluster-node1 postgres[1680]: [6-1] 2019-08-07 08:00:44 UTC LOG:  shutting down
Aug  7 08:00:45 cluster-node1 postgres[1982]: [10-1] 2019-08-07 08:00:45 UTC FATAL:  the database system is shutting down
Aug  7 08:00:45 cluster-node1 postgres[1983]: [10-1] 2019-08-07 08:00:45 UTC FATAL:  the database system is shutting down
Aug  7 08:00:48 cluster-node1 postgres[1984]: [10-1] 2019-08-07 08:00:48 UTC FATAL:  the database system is shutting down
```

Setup details:

1. All nodes are CentOS 7.6
2. PostgreSQL version is 11.

Note:

When i stop the PostgreSQL on secondary nodes, then PostgreSQL is able to successfully restart on primary node.

Comment: I have seen this error `background worker "logical replication worker" (PID xxxxx) exited with exit code 1` only once when we had transaction ID wraparound error on one of our PG 11 databases and database was not accepting any commands and there was active logical subscription (this was logical replica) and database tried to implement changes from logical replication master. Isn't there anything interesting in your log before that line "received fast shutdown request" line?

Comment: Added more logs. Please re-check.

Comment: Nice - this line `could not create IPv6 socket for address "::": Address family not supported by protocol` looks like your real problem - this is networking problem - look for example here - https://serverfault.com/questions/523687/could-not-create-ipv6-socket-postgresql-standby-error

Comment: Conventionally, `/etc/hosts` always have `::1` entry. I am not able to understand this.

Comment: Actually, sorry, my mistake - this is not error. There is message `Future log output will go to log destination "syslog"` - could you please look into syslog what happened between 07:58:55 and 08:00:44? Maybe OOM killer?